# Java Hibernate BUG when using query parameters in order clause

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, parameters, sql-order-by

When using query parameters the *ORDER BY* clause in combination with a *oneToMany* relation with the fetch strategy *subselect*, Hibernate 5.0.10 throws an exception: `java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column index`

The Problem: Hibernate executes the query perfectly. But afterwards, when loading the referenced *oneToMany* relation, it reuses parts of the query (especially the *WHERE* clause) to load all referenced entities. Some parts of the query, like the *ORDER BY* clause will be stripped off. Unfortunately, all query parameters from the original query were taken as they are into the subselect query without checking if they are still required. When Hibernate executes the subselect query it binds more parameters than there are in the query which leads to the exception.

Is it a bug or is it not supported in JPA?

#### edit - Adding quote from JPA spec

> Input parameters can only be used in the WHERE clause or HAVING clause of a query or as the new
>   value for an update item in the SET clause of an update statement.

But it would be a nice Hibernate feature anyway. Furthermore, the criteria API binds all literals as parameter. So it is not possible to use literals in the select/groupBy/orderBy clause using the criteria API. Is this also specified by JPA that way?

I have set up a scenario to replicate this issue:

#### SQL

```
CREATE TABLE "APERSON"
  (
    "ID"   VARCHAR2(50) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    "NAME" VARCHAR2(255)
  );
CREATE TABLE "AADDRESS"
  (
    "ID"     VARCHAR2(50) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    "PERSON" VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL, -- foreign key
    "NAME"   VARCHAR2(255)
  );
INSERT INTO "APERSON" (ID, NAME) VALUES ('1', 'me'); 
INSERT INTO "APERSON" (ID, NAME) VALUES ('2', 'you');
```

#### HBM mapping

```
<class entity-name="Person" table="APERSON">
  <id name="id" column="ID" type="string" />
  <property name="name" column="NAME" type="string" />
  <bag name="address" fetch="subselect" lazy="false" inverse="true">
    <key column="PERSON" />
    <one-to-many entity-name="Address" />
  </bag>
</class>
<class entity-name="Address" table="AADDRESS">
  <id name="id" column="ID" type="string" />
  <property name="name" column="NAME" type="string" />
</class>
```

#### Java

```
em.createQuery("SELECT p FROM Person p ORDER BY concat(:prefix, p.name)")
.setParameter("prefix", "any")
.getResultList(); //Exception here
```

#### edit - Inserted Log statements

You can see, that the first query executes nicely, but the second query results in an exception.

```
10:01:23,749 DEBUG [org.hibernate.SQL] (default task-22) select person0_.ID as ID1_1_, person0_.NAME as NAME2_1_ from APERSON person0_ order by ?||person0_.NAME
10:01:23,756 TRACE [org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder] (default task-22) binding parameter [1] as [VARCHAR] - [any]
10:01:23,766 DEBUG [org.hibernate.SQL] (default task-22) select address0_.PERSON as PERSON3_0_1_, address0_.ID as ID1_0_1_, address0_.ID as ID1_0_0_, address0_.NAME as NAME2_0_0_ from AADDRESS address0_ where address0_.PERSON in (select person0_.ID from APERSON person0_ )
10:01:23,770 TRACE [org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder] (default task-22) binding parameter [1] as [VARCHAR] - [any]
10:01:23,775 WARN  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (default task-22) SQL Error: 17003, SQLState: 99999
10:01:23,775 ERROR [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (default task-22) Invalid column index
```

Comment: Print the query after setting params and before calling `getResultSet` you can debug easily.

Comment: maybe your database system does not support the concat method?

Comment: Nope, thats not the problem. I've attached the logs where you can see, that the concat function is supported and works fine. The problem is the second query, when fetching the related entities of address.

Comment: JPA spec doesn't allow parameters in the ORDER BY clause. Some JPA providers allow it (e.g DataNucleus, since I use that), but no idea about Hibernate

Comment: @NeilStockton: Thank you, you are right. Maybe thats the reason why Hibernate doesn't support it. I've added a quote from JPA spec.

Comment: The JPA spec does NOT mandate that all literals be converted into parameters; that is JPA provider specific. The provider I use leaves all literals as literals, and all parameters as parameters, so then the user has control over what they're doing. If you put a literal in the ORDER BY and it is converted into a parameter does that mean that Hibernate fails? if so then report a BUG on your JPA provider.

Comment: @NeilStockton: Yes, Hibernate converts all literals (except integers and booleans) into parameters which results in the described problem. Actually I faced the problem first when using criteria API and literals in the ORDER BY clause.